# Is it possible to set the color space interpolation when using a d3 scale?

Tags: d3.js, colors

Let's say you construct some color scales in D3.js:

```
var color1 = d3.scale.linear()
            .range(['red','green']);

var color2 = d3.scale.quantile()
            .range(['red','green', 'blue']);

var color3 = d3.scale.quantize()
            .range(['red','green', 'blue']);
```

D3 will gladly interpolate those colors as needed for an input domain.

My question is: Is it possible to set the color interpolation for that interpolation computation to a lab or Hcl color space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like indeed it is. Use the interpolator thusly:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(["steelblue", "brown"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);
```

Comment: Is there a way to chain gamma() into this with your notation?

Comment: What does gamma() mean here? @Lucent

Comment: did you something like var interpolator = d3.interpolateRgb.gamma(2.2), then passing in the var?

Comment: This might be a v3 vs. v4 difference